# CSS - Fixed Position with Dynamic Width

Tags: html, css

I have a "search" container with a fixed width.  It has 2 children:

1. A "quantity" container that is anchored to the bottom right corner of the parent.  It's width is dynamic, but should always be quite a bit smaller than the parent container.
2. A "breadcrumbs" container that displays the current search criteria.  It's width can vary and even wrap.

I have managed to get this almost working, however there is an edge case where when "breadcrumbs" is a certain length, text from both child containers overlaps.

Below are some examples of how it should look and an example of how it is currently broken:

[image: sample]

And here is the HTML/CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.search {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.quantity {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<b>Sample 1</b>
<div class="search">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">Search Criteria: Blah Search Filter 1 &gt; Blah Search Filter 2 &gt; Blah Search Filter 3</div>
    <div class="quantity">51-100 of 5000</div>
</div>
<b>Sample 2</b>
<div class="search">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">Search Criteria: Blah Search Filter 1 &gt; Blah Search Filter 2 &gt; Blah Search Filter 3 &gt; Blah Search Filter 4</div>
    <div class="quantity">51-100 of 5000</div>
</div>
<b>Broken Sample</b>
<div class="search">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">Search Criteria: Blah Search Filter 1 &gt; Blah Search Filter 2 &gt; Blah Search Filter 3 &gt; Uh Oh!</div>
    <div class="quantity">51-100 of 5000</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** If it is not possible to do exactly what am am requesting, below is a potential alternative: [image: alternative]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the alternative you can just set `.breadcrumbs` to have `width:500px` or something, but @cimmanon has a good answer.

Comment: Making breadcrumbs fixed width may be the solution.  I was hoping the widths could be left dynamic though as `1 - 5 of 5` is a different width compared to `100 - 110 of 1000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without needing to change your markup, this CSS will work:

```
.search {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline;
}
.quantity {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mC5QG/ (minor modifications so you can see the full effect)

http://jsfiddle.net/mC5QG/2/ (added `margin-top: -1px` to `.quantity`)

Changed the absolute positioning to a float and set the first child element to `display: inline`.  Should work no matter what width the element is.

Alternate solution to match alternative appearance:

```
.search {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-row;
}

.breadcrumbs, .quantity {
    display: table-cell;
}

.breadcrumbs {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.quantity {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: pre;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mC5QG/1/

Comment: Your JSFiddle link just goes to jsfiddle.com

Comment: Yeah, just realized I forgot to save it ^^;

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely an improvement over what I have.  However I would like to have both child div's anchored to the bottom of the parent container.  There is a horizontal line under the parent container and it looks off if the bottom of the breadcrumbs container is not the same as the bottom of the quantity container.  As an FYI, I am free to change the HTML markup as necessary.

Comment: In Opera (didn't examine other browsers), there's only a 1px difference in the baseline of the child elements.  If removing the border is an option, then the 1px difference will be virtually unnoticeable.  You could potentially correct it via `line-height` or by adding `margin-top: -1px` to `.quantity`.